# How do I get a request header using NestJS?

Tags: nestjs

I have a simple app that returns `Something: Value` as a header. I currently have the following as a controller...

```
import { Controller, Get, Header } from "@nestjs/common";

@Controller("health")
export class HealthController {
  @Get()
  @Header("content-type", "application/json")
  checkHealth(): unknown {
    return {
      test: "This is the test",
    };
  }
}
```

In express I would expect to be able to do something like `req.headers` but I am not sure how to do that in nestjs.

Answer (score 10):

You should pass Headers from @nestjs/common as an argument to function:

```js
import { Controller, Get, Headers } from "@nestjs/common";

@Controller("health")
export class HealthController {
  @Get()
  checkHealth(@Headers() headers: Record < string, string > ) {
    return {
      test: "This is the test",
    };
  }
}
```

If you need just one header you can pass it's name to header like this:
`@Headers('content-type') headers: string`.

Alternatively if you want access to express req object you can also pass it to your controller

```js
import { Controller, Get, Req } from "@nestjs/common";
import { Request } from 'express';

@Controller("health")
export class HealthController {
  @Get()
  checkHealth(@Req() req: Request) {
    return {
      test: "This is the test",
    };
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You have two options to get the headers. You can use `@Req() req` in the route handler and then get `req.headers`, or you can use `@Headers() headers` in the route handler and then `headers` is the same as `req.headers`

```js
import { Controller, Get, Header, Headers } from "@nestjs/common";
import { Request } from 'express'; 
// OR
import { FastifyRequest } from 'fastify'

@Controller("health")
export class HealthController {
  @Get()
  @Header("content-type", "application/json")
  checkHealth(@Req() req: Request | FastifyRequest): unknown { // remove which isn't used here
    console.log(req.headers);
    return {
      test: "This is the test",
    };
  }
}
```

Or

```js
import { Controller, Get, Header, Headers } from "@nestjs/common";

@Controller("health")
export class HealthController {
  @Get()
  @Header("content-type", "application/json")
  checkHealth(@Headers() headers: Record<string, string>): unknown {
    console.log(headers);
    return {
      test: "This is the test",
    };
  }
}
```

Comment: I just want to add these methods are not identically the same. While with the `Request` option the uppercase letters in the headers remain, the `headers Record<>` option converts all letters to lowercase.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a decorator to pull out the headers from the request context.

```
export const RequestHeaders = createParamDecorator(
  async (ctx: ExecutionContext) => {
    // extract headers
    const headers = ctx.switchToHttp().getRequest().headers;
    return headers;
  },
```

and when used in a controller:

```
@Post('/route')
    async controllerMethod(@RequestHeaders() headers) {
    console.log(headers)
    // returns all headers in incoming request
    }
```

shamelessly stolen from this answer, thank you to whoever wrote it: https://github.com/nestjs/nest/issues/4798#issuecomment-706176390